# Easy way to submit an array field with Spring MVC forms?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a form with a list of nested fieldsets corresponding to a collection of objects, backed by a form object server-side. Fieldsets can be added or removed client-side. I want to submit a form without caring about object indices or sparse lists in command object.

Here's my Controller method code:

```
@PostMapping("/foobar")
public String doPost(FoobarForm form) {
    //...
}
```

In PHP, Rails etc it's very easy:

```
<input name="prop[]">
```

, and it will automatically populate `$_POST["prop"]` with all the values.

Working with Spring MVC, I tried these things:

1. `<input name="prop[]">` - doesn't work saying `Invalid property 'prop[]' of bean class [...]: Invalid index in property path 'prop[]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`
2. `<input name="prop">` - will not bind to a list-typed bean property, even when multiple fields present.
3. `<input name="prop[${i}]">` - implies all that hassle with sparse list and index handling, both client-side and server-side. Certainly not the right way to do things when working with a powerful web framework.

I'm wondering why can't I just use `[]` in property name and let Spring create a list automatically? It was asked [three times](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10723) on Spring JIRA without any reasonable responses.

Comment: What are you using for view resolver?  Thymeleaf, JSP?

Comment: You need to use SpEl (`${prop}`). Where is `prop` coming from?  Show complete code to get better help

Answer (score 1):

Spring form binding makes this more easy. You need to add List object in your bean and bind that in jsp using spring form.

```
class FoobarForm {
  List<String> prop;
}
```

In jsp, if you need to show/edit value all at once then `<form:input path="prop" />`
.if you want to show one by one then use indexing`<form:input path="prop[0]" />`. Use proper CommandName in form. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143477/4769751).
You can use the `MultiValueMap<String, String>`

```
@RequestMapping("foo")
public String bar(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters){ ... }
```

With these two inputs:

`<input name="prop" value="One">`
`<input name="prop" value="Two">`

the result will be {prop=["One","Two"]}

The code below will work too.

```
public String bar(@RequestParam("prop") List<String> props){ ... }
```