# Java Spring how to get all request parameters

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to get all request parameters in Java Spring? For example, in DJango you can do something like:

```
def view(request):
    print request.META
```

And from that you can see the `GET` or `POST` parameters that are sent, which is helpful for debugging. The only way I've seen to do this so far is by specifying the specific parameter, such as `@RequestParam(name="hello")`

Comment: Can you please confirm that you mean Spring, not JavaScript?  Maybe fixing the first sentence of your question would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes**!
You can do this by injecting the `HttpServletRequest` object in your endpoint by simple doing:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public String bar(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("Here you can see the creation time: " + request.getSession().getCreationTime());
    return "whatever string"; 
}
```

Then you can do just as following to list your parameters: [Get servlet parameters](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/get-all-request-parameters-in-servlet/)

Improving it (suggestion from @BoristheSpider) you can use the `MultiValueMap<String, String>` object that already maps all of your parameters into one object. So you can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public String bar(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters){ ... }
```

You can see an usage in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22399116/3798111).

Comment: Why not autowire a `MultiValueMap`? This seems to somewhat defeat the object of using Spring...

Comment: @BoristheSpider do you mean using a `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String>`? It will do the same internally. No problem with that :)

Comment: Many things will do the same internally - the point is to leverage the framework to do those things rather than do them yourself. That is literally the purpose of using a framework like Spring.

Comment: @Rhuan -- thanks for this. How would I then access a GET param, such as `request.get("hello")`?

Comment: To access this param you don't need to list all params @David542, you just need to add the parameter itself to your method, supposing that it's a String: `@RequestParam(name = "hello") String hello`. It will look like: `public String bar(@RequestParam(name = "hello") String hello) { ... }`

Comment: To get the parameter off the request class, use `String name = request.getParameter("name")`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my fault, you're totally right! Do you think I should correct my answer?

Comment: Maybe just expand on it, add in the other options as to how to achieve the result.